# How to create a password protection prompt when a user clicks a button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, password-protection

I have an HTML code that generates the below UI at (the bottom image). My goal is to create a pop-up password protection prompt when the Download Mapping and Upload Mapping buttons are clicked. Basically, the user can't upload or download a file without a password. How will I accomplish this? Thank you.

```
        <br />
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadMapping", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bolder;">Download Mapping</button>
        }

        <br />
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadMapping", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" class="btn btn-success" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bolder;">Upload Mapping</button>
        }

    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is,

- When you press each button call the jquery function (onClick
  function) and from you can open a pop-up
- then capture user name and password values from the pop-up and using
  an ajax call passes the data to the controller and validates them and
  get a response.
- If a user is a valid user you can simply return true or else return
  false